# Sqlite attach database using procedure/trigger that I will be able run it from c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I need attach database using procedure if it is possible.
My code is not working.

```
CREATE TRIGGER  MyTriger before insert on SysTableA for each row
BEGIN
attach 'C:\temp\database.db' as toMerge;  
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
insert into TableA select * from toMerge.TableA;
COMMIT;
END;
```

How to add this code to SQLlite?Sqlite doesn't support procedures.I tried to add to the triggers but I had same error.

I am using entity framework for dal connection to Sqlite. I need attach db and copy all the data.I wanted to do this operation inside of Sqlite and only to run it from C#.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html), you cannot put these commands into a trigger.

It might be possible for your C# application to register a user-defined function, to call it from the trigger, and to execute the commands from there, but that would require the cooperation of the C# application, so you could just as well execute the commands directly.

Comment: I am using entity framework.I didn't find the way how can I attach it from c#(not using old ADO technology).I need something like this.

Comment: using (var context = new Db())
 {
   // attach 'C:\temp\database.db' as toMerge
 }